# Prove that the dimension of row space equals to the dimension of column space of an $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Knowing that the row space of $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ equals $N(A)^\perp$ prove that the dimension of column space of a matrix equals its row space dimension.

So I'm trying to apply properties of dimensions in this proof like:

$\dim (U^{\perp}) = \dim V - \dim U $

But I don't know any dimension (except V which might be $n \times n$) Can someone give a hint in how to proceed to start this proof?

Thanks!

Comment: You may use [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem), as well.

Comment: What does "except $V$ which might be $m×n$" mean?

Comment: Isn't the dimension of a matrix $m \times n$ equal to $m \times n$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $n \times n$

Comment: According to what you wrote, $V$ should be the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is a linear transformation on $V$.

Comment: Oh right sorry for my mistake! It should be $ n + n$ right?

Comment: Do you know what is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^ n$?

Comment: n, right? but here we're talking about matrices aren't we? So it should be n+n or just n?

Comment: $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation, which is, using your language, an $n\times n$ matrix. The rank-nullity theorem tells you the relations among three things: the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the dimension of the range of $A$ (i.e., the column space of $A$), and the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of $N(A)^\perp$, one has
$$
\dim (N(A)^\perp)+\dim(N(A))=n.
$$
By the rank–nullity theorem, 
$$
\dim (N(A))+\dim R(A)=n.
$$
Now, by cancellation you have the proof.

Comment: Ok I understood! For moments I got confused about a thing, please clarify me: is the dimension of a matrix m x n equal to m x n, right?

Comment: That is incorrect. The dimension of the space of *all* the $m\times n$ matrix is $m\times n$. We talk about the dimension of a *vector space*. An $m\times n$ matrix is an *element* of a vector space.

Comment: I think I got it. If we talk about the space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ it has dimension $m \times n$. But it doesn't make sense to talk about the dimension of a single matrix (we only talk about its nullspace and rank). Thanks very much!